# Rescaling the colors in a colormap and the axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have cerated a file (workfile.dat) at the following format:

```
<x1> >y1> <z>
<x1> >y2> <z>
<x1> >y3> <z>

<x2> >y1> <z>
<x2> >y2> <z>
<x2> >y3> <z>

etc.
```

I have created a surf pgf:

[image: picture]

using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},colormap/cool]
  \addplot3[surf] table [row sep=newline] {./workfile.dat};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i would like that where the value of `<z>` is null that it would be white and not like in the above picture. I would like it to look like something like this:

[image: expected picture]

This mean that the x-axis is represented by decimal format with two digits after the point and the y-axis is from 0 to 1 (instead of 0 to 400).

In addition i would like to know if it is possible in tikz pgf to use LogNorm for the color bar like in matplotlib.

**EDIT**

here is an example of what i did:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
               colormap/cool,
               y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/400}]
   \addplot3[surf] table [row sep=newline] {./workfile.dat};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this is the output i get: [image: Output]

The blue lines seems to be correct, but i cant explain the gray background at the places where  = 0.

**EDIT 2**

new example:

file data workfile.dat

```
1 1 0
1 2 0

2 1 0
2 2 1
```

output [image: file]

code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
             colormap/cool,
    ]
  \addplot3[surf] table [row sep=newline] {./workfile_2.dat};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, only one element in the input data have the value "1", but nether the less, the all area is blue.

Comment: Hm, that's a strange result. The `cool` colormap doesn't contain gray. Can you make a comple minimal working example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: The second picture contains a gray line color (it is not one to one). It was a line that was added above a imshow plot in matplotlib.

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand your request: you want the color map to be "modified" such that z=0 has color white, right? The second picture with the line plot has nothing to do with a surface plot at all. Perhaps what you want is a contour plot - and perhaps only with contours for z=0?

Comment: @Christian, you are right what is important for me is that <z> = 0 it would be the color white (2nd picture) instead of gray (1st picture).

Comment: @Eagle: Which colormap did you use to create the first picture (not `cool`, right?)? What is the range of `z` values in your data? For rescaling the `y` range, you can use `y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/400}`, and for taking the logarithm of the `z` values you can use `z filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{ln(\pgfmathresult)}`.

Comment: @Jake, i did use cool, just like in is in the code example i gave.The maximum value of <z> is about 1000 in this example.

Comment: @Jake, i will have a problem applying: `z filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{ln(\pgfmathresult)}` since i have <z> values that have the value null and `ln(0)` is not defined. Is it possible to take only <z> values which are bigger or equal to 1?

Comment: @Eagle: Could you post your datafile (or an extract of it, or a dummy file that leads to the same results)?

Comment: @Jake, i could post my datafile, but it contains 401000 lines and i don't know how to attached a file in stackexchange. I hope that my short example is sufficient, if not, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per definition, a surface plot (`surf`) always fills the complete area by means of a "suitable" color of the `colormap`. Here, *complete* means that the background of the axis (white) is no longer visible.

In order to see "white", you have to decide if a surface plot is really what you want. If this turns out to be true (according to your question, this seems to be the case), you have primarily ONE choice: namely to define a colormap for which the value of z=0 happens to be mapped to color white.

If, however, you simply wanted to see the background color (white) and want to see a couple of lines of fixed height, you might be better off using a contour plot. I would suggest you go with a contour plot since it looks closer to your second 2d picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
             colormap/cool,
             colorbar,
    ]
  \addplot3[contour gnuplot] table [row sep=newline] {
  1 1 0
1 2 0

2 1 0
2 2 1
  };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you really want to have a `surf` plot, you can still proceed as follows:

Here is an initial attempt to define a "suitable" `colormap` - i.e. one for which you have a `surf` plot for which z=0 happens to get color white:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
             colormap={custom}{color(0)=(red) color(2)=(white) color(4)=(blue)},
             colorbar,
    ]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] table [row sep=newline] {
  1 1 0
1 2 0

2 1 0
2 2 1
  };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
             colormap={custom}{color(0)=(red) color(1)=(white) color(2)=(green) color(4)=(blue)},
             colorbar,
    ]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] table [row sep=newline] {
  1 1 0
1 2 0

2 1 0
2 2 1
  };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this approach, you may want to choose the correct value for `shader` (my choice works, another suitable one might be `flat corner` for your application).

I believe that the contour plot solution is what might prove to be better (less work and prettier for this application - provided the computed contours of your data are good enough).

Comment: thank you for your answer. At the moment i get the following error: "I do not know the key '/tikz/contour gnuplot'". I added \usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz} for gnuplot, but contour is still a problem.

Comment: Support for contour plots has been added in Version 1.5 . Perhaps it is unavailable without updating your installation (the most recent stable version of pgfplots is 1.5.1).

Comment: I upgrade yesterday to v1.5.1. I saw that if i use `lualatex -shell-escape foo.tex` i get not what you got and if i use `pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex` i get what you got. Since my data file is big, i am forced to use lualatex. Are you aware of this problem?

Comment: No, this is news for me... I will look into it. Thanks for the report...

Comment: I looked into it and found that the binary output used by `shader=interp` does not work with lualatex. Until I fixed this, you will need to use another shader (like `shader=flat corner`).

Comment: The incompatibility lualatex and `shader=interp` is fixed now; will become part of the next stable (probably 1.5.2).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I will repeat this every now and then but thank you for this wonderful package. FYI, it has been in IEEE publications at least 5 times now. :)

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the praise! I appreciate it :-)